# Nougat notifications blocked even after uninstalling "Notifications Off", how to reset?

Tags: notifications, 7.1-nougat

I was a happy user of [Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) on Android 6.0.
It is an app that lets you block/unblock notifications per app.
On Android 7.1.2 blocking works but unblocking does not work, according to my experience and Play Store reviews.

**My question**: How to reset notifications, so that all appear?

I tried uninstalling the app, that does not unblock blocked notifications.
Anything easier than reinstalling the OS?

If I knew how Notifications Off works under the hood, I could maybe try to unblock manually?

Comment: That app hasn't been updated for a couple of years. That's probably why it didn't work on Nougat. Try [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). It's an automation app but has an action of Configure app notifications . (Set trigger as empty trigger). In this you can try toggling all to undo settings of that app and configure. I don't have Nougat to test but this app is Nougat ready as I read in app forums

Comment: Try wiping cache partition, and see if this  resolves the issue

Comment: @xavier_fakerat: I just wiped the Dalvik cache+cache partitions with TWRP, it does not solve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the author and here is his reply:

> Looks like a compatibility issue with Android 7. As a workaround to enable notifications you need to go to Gmail in the applications list and enable notifications there.

And indeed it is as simple as this:

1. Go to Android Settings.
2. Tap "Notifications".
3. Select "Blocked".
4. For each app that you want to unblock, tap it and move the slider to the right, for instance the 5th position out of 7.

The notifications are now reset to visible level again.